# Twitter Sign in page always showing

Tags: twitter, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I have implemented Sign in with Twitter on my web site using DotNetOpenAuth lib using asp.net mvc 3.

My problem is that every time the user click Sign-in with twitter it redirects him to a twitter page (even if he is already logged in to twitter).

I saw that sites like www.pinterest.com avoids this somehow.

How can I avoid the redirect to Twitter sign-in page if the user is already logged in to twitter?

Comment: Is the user actually being redirected to the Twitter *login* page as your question suggests, or is the user only redirecting to the Twitter *authorization* path (with a yes/no approval button)?

Comment: This is the exact url the user is redirected to (I changed the token a little...): 
https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=AAAAtew6CUVzcHRitB6p9j0W374bcTQRCOHRrjxR40

Comment: Sorry..  that doesn't answer my question really.  I'm wondering what is on the page in the scenario you're describing?

Comment: Oh, Than twitter authorization path it is. Using https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-twitter). Redirect users to `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=xyz` instead of `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xyz`. If the user is has an active session with twitter.com and has previously authorized the application they will silently be redirected to the callback url.