# Twitter OAuth with ASP.NET MVC 4 requiring sign-in every time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter, oauth

I'm using the out-of-the-box OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterTwitterClient function in ASP.NET MVC 4. I have set up a Twitter app, and I have enabled "sign in with twitter". The problem is that when I click the button, it makes me log into Twitter EVERY TIME, even if I'm already logged in in a different tab. Note that I have read the following question/answers:

[Twitter Sign in page always showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379853/twitter-sign-in-page-always-showing)

[Simple Twitter Oauth authorization asking for credentials every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578881/simple-twitter-oauth-authorization-asking-for-credentials-every-time)

which detail that it needs to go to the /authenticate/ endpoint instead of /authorize/. I have already done this, the URL that it redirects to is:

https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=token_here&force_login=false

I have also tried it with the /authorize/ endpoint, but that doesn't work either. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the 'force_login' parameter doesn't work how you'd think it would work. If the 'force_login' parameter is present then it will always force a login, regardless if it is true or false. If you remove it, it will work as expected.

Change:

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=token_here&force_login=false
```

To:

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=token_here
```

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to take this param out.

Sooo, to fix this you could implement the Twitter SDK. Or leave it and wait for Microsoft to fix it; but I wouldn't hold my breath.

EDIT:
This answer works. I've tried it myself.

[MVC4's DotNetOpenAuth TwitterClient sample does not respect prior login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034084/mvc4s-dotnetopenauth-twitterclient-sample-does-not-respect-prior-login)